# Using standard error 404 instead of wordpress 404 - htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i want to use the standard server 404 page instead of the wordpress 404 redirect page done through this htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

But i still want to use permalinks. Can someone help me to modify the htaccess file that i can get the normal error 404 of my server back?
thank you

Comment: Actually that's not possible. The htaccess rewrites everything to the index.php, so there will never be a 404 your webserver could send. You need to modify wordpress instead.

Comment: You can simulate standard 404 error page...

Comment: @charlotte: how can i do that?

Comment: Look for the piece of code in wordpress which sends a 404 page and replace it with what you want to see.

Comment: okay than its not going to work. i already designed the error 404 page but google keeps visiting old non existing files on my server. I thought that the server responses keeps google from doing that :(

Comment: @Charlotte Dunois: no need to change WordPress core; a 404.php file can be added to the theme. And no, WordPress does not rewrite everything to index.

Answer (score 1):

Make your own 404.php file and put it in your theme folder. That way, you can get the 404 page to look the way you want, either a standard 404 page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
```

or one styled to the theme.

Either way, check with the console or dev tools to be sure you're getting a correct 404 header.

If not, send a 404 header with PHP so your sends a true 404 response that search engines understand by using

`<?php header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); ?>`

at the top of your 404.php file.

Comment: In my experience, not all the time; added details to answer.

Comment: like i wrote above i have already designed this file, but google keeps visiting old non existing files on my server. I thought that the server responses keeps google from doing that :(

Comment: Google may keep doing that, as well as other search bots; create a sitemap.xml, a robots.txt file and use Google's Webmaster's Tools to better control Google's indexing and bots.